# PFX ConcurrentQueue - is there a way to remove a specific item from the queue

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, pfx

I have an app that has a ConcurrentQueue of items that have an ID property and a ConcurrentQueue of tasks for each item, the queue items look like:

```
class QueueItem {
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public ConcurrentQueue<WorkItem> workItemQueue { get; set; }
}
```

and the queue itself looks like:

```
ConcurrentQueue<QueueItem> itemQueue;
```

I have one thread doing a foreach over the itemQueue, deQueueing an item from each queue and doing work on it:

```
foreach(var queueItem in itemQueue) {
  WorkItem workItem;
  if (queueItem.workItemQueue.TryDequeue(out workItem))
    doWork(workItem);
  else
    // no more workItems for this queueItem
}
```

I'm using ConcurrentQueues because I have a separate thread potentially adding queueItems to the itemQueue, and adding workItems to each workItemQueue.

My problem comes when I have no more workItems in a queueItem - I'd like to remove that queueItem from the itemQueue - something like...

```
  if (queueItem.workItemQueue.TryDequeue(out workItem))
    doWork(workItem);
  else
    itemQueue.TryRemove(queueItem);
```

...but I can't find a way to do that easily.  The way i've come up with is to dequeue each QueueItem and then Enqueue it if there's still WorkItems in the workItemQueue:

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemQueue.Count; i++) {
  QueueItem item;
  itemQueue.TryDequeue(out queueItem);
  if (queueItem.workItemQueue.TryDequeue(out workItem)) {
    itemQueue.Enqueue(queueItem);
    doWork(workItem);
  }
  else
    break;
}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish what I want using the PFX ConcurrentQueue, or is this a reasonable way to do this, should I use a custom concurrent queue/list implementation or am I missing something?

Comment: No Idea personally. PFX's kind of new but I'm surpised nobody answered your question so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, there is no efficient ways to remove specific items from queues. They generally have O(1) queue and dequeues, but O(n) removes, which is what your implementation does.

One alternative structure is something called a LinkedHashMap. Have a look at the [Java implementation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) if you are interested.

It is essentially a Hash table *and* a linked list, which allows O(1) queue, dequeue and remove.

This isn't implemented in .Net yet, but there are a few implementations floating around the web.

Now, the question is, why is itemQueue a queue? From your code samples, you never enqueue or dequeue anything from it (except to navigate around the Remove problem). I have a suspicion that your problem could be simplified if a more suitable data structure is used. Could you give examples on what other pieces of code access itemQueue?

Answer (score 4):

This may not work for everyone, but the following is the solution I came up with for removing an item from a concurrent queue, since this is the first google result, I thought I would leave my solution behind.

What I did was temporarily replace the working queue with an empty, convert the original to a list and remove the item(s), then create a new queue from the modified list and put it back.

In code (sorry this is VB.net rather C#):

```
Dim found As Boolean = False
//'Steal the queue for a second, wrap the rest in a try-finally block to make sure we give it back
Dim theCommandQueue = Interlocked.Exchange(_commandQueue, New ConcurrentQueue(Of Command))
Try
    Dim cmdList = theCommandQueue.ToList()
    For Each item In cmdList
        If item Is whateverYouAreLookingFor Then
            cmdList.Remove(item)
            found = True
        End If
    Next
    //'If we found the item(s) we were looking for, create a new queue from the modified list.
    If found Then
        theCommandQueue = New ConcurrentQueue(Of Command)(cmdList)
    End If
Finally
    //'always put the queue back where we found it
    Interlocked.Exchange(_commandQueue, theCommandQueue)
End Try
```

Aside: This is my first answer, so feel free to put up some editing advice and/or edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Queues are meant when you want to handle items in a FIFO style, Stacks for LIFO.  There is also a concurrentdictionary and a concurrentbag.  Make sure that a queue is actually what you want.  I don't think I would ever do a foreach on a concurrentqueue.

What you likely want is a single queue for your work items (have them use a common interface and make a queue on the interface, the interface should expose the inherited type to which it can be recast later if needed).  If the workitems belong to a parent, then a property can be used which will hold a key to the parent (consider a GUID for the key), and the parent can be kept in a concurrentdictionary and referenced/removed as needed.

If you must do it the way you have it, consider adding a flag.  you can then mark the item in the itemqueue as 'closed' or whatever, so that when it is dequeued, it will get ignored.